# Bokeh not interpreting correct scale with SQL data

Tags: python, sqlite, bokeh

Explored lots of various solutions here but not finding one that works.  I'm using sqlite and pandas to read data from a SQL database, but Bokeh doesn't like the date.  I've tried conversions to datetime, unixepoch, etc. and they all seem to yield the same result.

EDIT: Here's the full code:

```
from os.path import dirname, join

import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import numpy as np
import sqlite3
import os

from math import pi

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show 
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Div, DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, Select, RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox

import warnings
import datetime

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


## Set up the SQL Connection

conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/<>/Documents/python_scripts/reptool/reptool_db')
c = conn.cursor()

## Run the SQL

proj = pd.read_sql(
                       """

                        SELECT  

                        CASE WHEN df is null THEN ds ELSE df END AS 'projdate',
                        CASE WHEN yhat is null THEN y ELSE yhat END AS 'projvol',
                        strftime('%Y',ds) as 'year'

                        FROM forecast 

                        LEFT JOIN actuals 
                        ON forecast.ds = actuals.df 

                       """, con=conn)


# HTML index page and inline CSS stylesheet

desc = Div(text=open("/Users/<>/Documents/python_scripts/reptool/description.html").read(), width=800)


## Rename Columns and create list sets

proj.rename(columns={'projdate': 'x', 'projvol': 'y'}, inplace=True)

x=list(proj['x'])
y=list(proj['y'])

# proj['projdate'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d").date() for x in proj['projdate']]

# Create input controls


radio_button_group = RadioButtonGroup(
        labels=["Actuals", "Forecast","FY Projection"], active=0)

min_year = Slider(title="Period Start", start=2012, end=2018, value=2013, step=1)
max_year = Slider(title="Period End", start=2012, end=2018, value=2017, step=1)

## Declare systemic source

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[], year=[]))


## Bokeh tools

TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,xbox_select"

## Set up plot


p = figure(title="REP Forecast", plot_width=900, plot_height=300, tools=TOOLS, x_axis_label='date', x_axis_type='datetime', y_axis_label='volume', active_drag="xbox_select")

p.line(x=proj.index, y=y, line_width=2, line_alpha=0.6)


p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4

# p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(seconds=["%Y:%M"],
#                                             minutes=["%Y:%M"],
#                                             minsec=["%Y:%M"],
#                                             hours=["%Y:%M"])

# axis map


# definitions

def select_rep():
    selected = proj[
        (proj.year >= min_year.value) &
        (proj.year >= max_year.value)
    ]
    return selected

def update():
    proj = select_rep()
    source.data = dict(
        year=proj["year"]   
    )



controls = [min_year, max_year]
for control in controls:
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())


sizing_mode = 'fixed'  # 'scale_width' also looks nice with this example

## Build the html page and inline CSS
inputs = widgetbox(*controls)
l = layout([
    [desc],
    [p],
    [inputs],
], )

# update()

curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "REP"
```

The SQLite output in Terminal.app looks like this:

[SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9z45.png)

The result is, that the x-axis displays in milliseconds.  Also, the y-axis is showing up as exponential notation:

[Bokeh Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xLEH.png)

The issue seems somehow related to pandas use of indexing, and thus I can't reference "x" here.  I rename the columns and force list sets which, by themselves, will print correctly... and should therefore plot into the line properly but as you'll see below, they don't:

```
proj.rename(columns={'projdate': 'x', 'projvol': 'y'}, inplace=True)

x=list(proj['x'])
y=list(proj['y'])
```

To get the line to render in Bokeh, I have to pass it the index because passing it anything else doesn't seem to get the glyph to render. So currently I have this:

```
p = figure(title="REP Forecast", plot_width=900, plot_height=300, tools=TOOLS, x_axis_label='date', x_axis_type='datetime', y_axis_label='volume', active_drag="xbox_select")

p.line(x=proj.index, y=y, line_width=2, line_alpha=0.6)
```

Tried converting to unixepoch in the SQL, same result.
Tried converting to unixepoch in the data, same result.
Tried using DateTimeTickFormatter, just shows all 5-6 years as one year (thinking it's just displaying the milliseconds as years rather than changing them from milliseconds to days.

I've looked here and in github, up and down, and tried different things but ultimately I can't find one working example where the source is a sql query not a csv.

Answer (score 0):

None of these things have anything to do with SQL, Bokeh only cares about the data that you give it, not where it came from. You have specified that you want a datetime axis on the x-axis:

```
x_axis_type='datetime'
```

So, Bokeh will set up the plot with a ticker that picks "nice" values on a datetime scale, and with a tick formatter that displays tick locations as formatted dates. What is important, however, is that the data coordinates are in the appropriate units, which are *floating point milliseconds since epoch*.

You can provide x values directly in these units, but Bokeh will also automatically convert common datetime types (e.g. python stdlib, numpy, or pandas) to the right units automatically. So the easiest thing for you to do is pass a column of datetime values as the x values to `line`.

To be clear, this statement:

> To render the line in Bokeh, it has to use the index

is incorrect. You can pass any dataframe column you like as the x-values, and I am suggesting you pass a column of datetimes.

Comment: Bokeh isn't responding to anything I pass to it except proj.index... So what would be the correct way to pass the x-value to it? I've tried to follow every example I could find, and it doesn't work. But pass proj.index to it, and it "works", except the timescale is completely wonky and it just leads me to further workarounds... If I'm doing something wrong, what is the correct way, using SQL, pandas and Bokeh, that works?

Comment: You haven't given enough code,or even the types of the columns in your dateframe or example data, to say more than what is above. With a minimal, complete, reproducing example it would be possible to diagnose directly.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the full code ("<>" to hide userid's), screenshots of the SQL output and the Bokeh output.  Note I'm still working on the sliders (I expect them to be nonfunctional for now) but the bokeh plot is my current concern.

Comment: What is the output of  `df.head()`

Comment: proj.head() yields output like this:

2011-08-01 00:00:00 57923.78228 2011

Comment: Are those strings, or actual datetimes? If they are strings, they need to be converted to real datetimes. Strings are interpreted as categorical values. When I do `SELECT strftime('%Y', foo) as 'bar' FROM table"` with `pd.read_sql` on a sample data set I see strings. I reiterate what I said earlier: *I am suggesting you pass a column of datetimes.*

Comment: The field is datetime but the content is likely a string.  I tried importing them as datetime from Excel, but the only way I was able to get Excel to hold the correct datetime format exporting to CSV was using a text conversion.... I could either try what you're suggesting above or try some other conversion in excel if it would ever stick.  Let me try the first (your suggestion) and see where that gets me.

Comment: See e.g. `parse_dates` option in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: I changed a line of the SQL to:  
  
`CASE WHEN df is null THEN strftime('%Y',ds) ELSE strftime('%Y',df) END AS 'projdate',`

And also by re-importing the data I was able to pass the date through here without using Index:

`p.line(x=x, y=y, line_width=2, line_alpha=0.6)`

But then I get this weird output: [link](https://i.imgur.com/behUKwS.png).  

So it's clear that it can read the year, but I need the full date.  I'll try the parser and a few other things... but if you have a tangible example that works, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a line of the SQL to:

`CASE WHEN df is null THEN strftime('%Y',ds) ELSE strftime('%Y',df) END AS 'projdate',`

However, when I try expanding that specifier to %Y-%m-%d %H-%m-%s it just reads it as a string all over again.

And also by re-importing the data I was able to pass the date through here without using Index:

`p.line(x=x, y=y, line_width=2, line_alpha=0.6)`

But then I get this weird output: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlSpw.png).

So it's clear that it can read the year, but I need to pass through the full date to display the time series forecast.  And it's still displaying the dates and y-values in the incorrect scale, regardless.

Going to noodle on this some more but if anyone has other suggestions, I'm thankful.

Comment: `strftime('%Y',ds)` is specifically extracting only the year, that's all `%Y` does. If you want more information you need a different `strftime` field specifier

Comment: I'm aware of that... I lost a snippet of my response:  When I try expanding that specifier to `%Y-%m-%d %H-%m-%s` it just reads it as a string all over again.

Comment: Did you set `parse_dates` (linked below) in you call to `read_sql`? Pandas won't interpret things as dates unless you tell it to.

Comment: No, I had not.  I did see your other comment, though.  Thanks... I'm giving that a try.

Comment: parse_dates didn't work but it led me to something that does.  I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED the datetime problem. Added this after the SQL query:

```
proj['projdate'] = proj['projdate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Which in turn yields this:

[Bokeh Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIe8z.png)

Still got a problem with the x-axis but since that's a straight numerical value, `x_axis_type` should fix it.

So far the working code looks like this (again, still iterating to add other controls but everything about the Bokeh plot itself works as intended):

```
# main.py

# created by:           <>
# version:              0.1.2
# created date:         07-Aug-2018
# modified date:        09-Aug-2018

from os.path import dirname, join

import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import numpy as np
import sqlite3
import os

from math import pi

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show 
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Div, DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, Select, RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox

import warnings
import datetime

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


## Set up the SQL Connection

conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/<>/Documents/python_scripts/reptool/reptool_db')
c = conn.cursor()

## Run the SQL

proj = pd.read_sql(
                       """

                        SELECT  

                        CASE WHEN df is null THEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d',ds) ELSE strftime('%Y-%m-%d',df) END AS 'projdate',
                        CASE WHEN yhat is null THEN y ELSE yhat END AS 'projvol',
                        strftime('%Y',ds) as 'year'

                        FROM forecast 

                        LEFT JOIN actuals 
                        ON forecast.ds = actuals.df 

                       """, con=conn)

proj['projdate'] = proj['projdate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')


# HTML index page and inline CSS stylesheet

desc = Div(text=open("/Users/<>/Documents/python_scripts/reptool/description.html").read(), width=800)


## Rename Columns and create list sets

proj.rename(columns={'projdate': 'x', 'projvol': 'y'}, inplace=True)

x=list(proj['x'])
y=list(proj['y'])


# Create input controls


radio_button_group = RadioButtonGroup(
        labels=["Actuals", "Forecast","FY Projection"], active=0)

min_year = Slider(title="Period Start", start=2012, end=2018, value=2013, step=1)
max_year = Slider(title="Period End", start=2012, end=2018, value=2017, step=1)

## Declare systemic source

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[], year=[]))


## Bokeh tools

TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,xbox_select"

## Set up plot


p = figure(title="REP Forecast", plot_width=900, plot_height=300, tools=TOOLS, x_axis_label='date', x_axis_type='datetime', y_axis_label='volume', active_drag="xbox_select")

p.line(x=x, y=y, line_width=2, line_alpha=0.6)


p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4

# p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(seconds=["%Y:%M"],
#                                             minutes=["%Y:%M"],
#                                             minsec=["%Y:%M"],
#                                             hours=["%Y:%M"])

# axis map


# definitions

def select_rep():
    selected = proj[
        (proj.year >= min_year.value) &
        (proj.year >= max_year.value)
    ]
    return selected

def update():
    proj = select_rep()
    source.data = dict(
        year=proj["year"]   
    )



controls = [min_year, max_year]
for control in controls:
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())


sizing_mode = 'fixed'  # 'scale_width' also looks nice with this example

## Build the html page and inline CSS
inputs = widgetbox(*controls)
l = layout([
    [desc],
    [p],
    [inputs],
], )

# update()

curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "REP"
```